# How to include links at the end of a row in a WebGrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I am trying to display data in an MVC3 application that shows data from a database. Originally I hacked together a solution using tables which can be seen here: [image: first picture].

I later updated my view so as to use a Webgrid instead: [image: WebGrid]
 I would like to include the Edit and Delete links from my first effort into the Webgrid solution. Does anyone know how I can do this (I could make some of the entries in the webgrid into links-this would be suitable for the edit option but not for the delete)

Current View code:

```
 
    @model IEnumerable

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "DisplayMembers";
    }

   DisplayMembers  

    @{  var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canSort: false, canPage: true, defaultSort: "UserRoleId"); }



     @grid.GetHtml(
                    tableStyle: "dataGrid",
                    headerStyle: "header",
                    alternatingRowStyle: "evenRow", 
                    columns: grid.Columns
          (
              grid.Column(header: "User Role ID", columnName: "UserRoleId"),
              grid.Column(header: "UserName", columnName: "UserName"),
              grid.Column(header: "Role ", columnName: "Role"),
              grid.Column(header: "Active", columnName: "ActiveInd")
      ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help

```
grid.Column(header: "Edit", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAction", "ControllerName", new{@userRoleId=@item.UserRoleId})</text>),
grid.Column(header: "Delete", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteAction", "ControllerName", new { @userRoleId= @item.UserRoleId})</text>)
```

Comment: that just repeats the username column at the end. I actually want a column of edit links and a separate column of delete links as in the first picture in the main post

Answer (score 1):

I solved it be using an HTML.Actionlink as follows:

```
grid.Column(columnName: "Select", header: "", 
format:@<text>@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Create", new {item.Name},null) </text>)
```

Comment: can you explain what you're doing here as i can't make sense of this. What are the meanings of 'select', 'create' and 'name'?

Comment: the documentation for the method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx
Basically: Select is the text to be shown, Create is the controller method to be called, item.Name is my argument to the controller and null is a place where you can put html attributes.